# How to stretch waveform using audiokit

Tags: swift, audio, audiokit, waveform, amplitude

I'm tracking the amplitude while outputting it as a waveform in real time. I'm using audiokitUI's RollingViewData class to do this with the results as seen below.

My issue is the waveform is very small insensitive to input, maybe looks like the node needs to go through a booster before being plotted? How would i achieve this and are there any methods that do so in audio kit v5? Thanks

[image: screenshot of waveform output]

Comment: A simple way would be to add a `.scaleEffect(x: 1: y: 2)` for SwiftUI